# R: Sorting a data frame by column value using the order() function results in error

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working on a R function. I have the following code:

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
    ##Read outcome data
    data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv")

    #rename some of the columns
    names(data)[names(data) == "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack"] <- "heart_attack_rate"

    names(data)[names(data) == "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"] <- "heart_failure_rate"

    names(data)[names(data) == "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia"] <- "pneumonia_rate"

    print(names(data))

    states <- unique(data$State)

    ##check that the state and the outcome are valid
    outcomes <- c("heart attack", "heart failure", "pneumonia")

    if(!is.element(state, states)) {
        stop("invalid state")
    }

    if(!is.element(outcome, outcomes)) {
        stop("invalid outcome")
    }

    ##Return hospital name in that state with the lowest 30-day death rate
    newdata <- NULL

    if(outcome == "heart attack") {
        newdata <- subset(data, State == state & heart_attack_rate != "Not Available", select=c(Hospital.Name, State, heart_attack_rate))
        sorted_data <- newdata[order(heart_attack_rate), ]
    }

    else if(outcome == "heart failure") {
        newdata <- subset(data, State == state & heart_failure_rate != "Not Available", select=c(Hospital.Name, State, heart_failure_rate))
        sorted_data <- newdata[order(heart_failure_rate), ]
    }

    else {
        newdata <- subset(data, State == state & pneumonia_rate != "Not Available", select=c(Hospital.Name, State, pneumonia_rate))
        sorted_data <- newdata[order(pneumonia_rate), ]
    }
}
```

The above function takes a state and outcome as parameters. Depending on these parameters, I am making a subset of the original data frame. I have renamed some of the columns in the data frame in order for the names to be more readable.

For the columns `heart_attack_rate`, `heart_failure_rate` and `pneumonia_rate` I want to sort the data frame by these column values. E.g. this is done in the following line:

```
sorted_data <- newdata[order(heart_attack_rate), ]
```

However, when I run the function with the following inputs:

```
best("TX", "heart attack")
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in order(heart_attack_rate) : object 'heart_attack_rate' not found
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error or how to resolve it. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to say: `order(newdata$heart_attack_rate)` in that line? This would apply to the subsequent lines as well: `order(newdata$heart_failure_rate)` and `order(newdata$pneumonia_rate)`. Just to clarify -- I think you mean to reference these variables within a data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that makes complete sense, since if `newdata` is a data.frame there is no reference of `heart_attack_rate` in the complete function.

Consider this example using built-in `mtcars` dataset

```
mtcars[order(cyl), ]
```

> Error in order(cyl) : object 'cyl' not found

You need to refer the column name using `$`

```
mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl), ]

#                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
#Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
#Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
#....
```

Or use `with` :

```
mtcars[with(mtcars, order(cyl)), ]
```

---

As a sidenote, if the data is `data.table` your attempt would have worked.

```
library(data.table)
df <- mtcars
setDT(df)
df[order(cyl),]
#Or
#df[order(cyl)]


#     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1: 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# 2: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# 3: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# 4: 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# 5: 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
#....
```